# Rails model validates and tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a simple Rails 4 application, and I'm trying to write some tests to check my user signup is working properly.
I have a problem that when I'm running testcases with my hands, everything works ok, but when I write some integration tests and run them it skips my model's validations, so I'm getting database exceptions like

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_username"


test 'unique username violated' do
    params = user_params               # it is just a hash with User model attributes
    User.new(params).save              # saving user first time to violate unique after        
    params[:email] = 'Test@Email2'
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
        post users_path, user: params
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
end
```

Example of my validation is below:

```
validates :username, :email, \
  uniqueness: {uniqueness: true, message: 'Username&email must be unique'}, \
  length: {maximum: 50, message: 'Length must be <= 50'}
```

It's not only this validation issue, but all the rest are not working in tests too.

If I'll validate my user object with something like, inside of a test, it will be false, as it should be.

```
User.new(params).valid?
```

My users#create action is below:

```
def create
    @user = User.new user_params
    if @user.save
        flash[:success] = 'Welcome to the Sample App!'
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
 end
```

my users#user_params method:

```
def user_params
    user_group = UserGroup.find_by_name 'administrator'
    if user_group.nil?
        user_group = UserGroup.new name: 'administrator'
        user_group.save
    end
    {username: 'TestUsername', password: 'TestPassword', \
password_confirmation: 'TestPassword', email: 'Test@Email', \
firstname: 'TestFirstname', lastname: 'TestLastname',user_group: user_group}
end
```

Comment: try uniqueness: {message: 'Username&email must be unique'}

Comment: well, that's the same, nothing changed.

Comment: show your User#create action

Comment: updated the question with the users#create body

Answer (score 0):

Rails validations don't really work that way. When you use:

```
validates :username, :email, uniqueness: true
```

You are adding a similar but separate validations for `:username` and `:email`. Consider this case:

```
user = User.new
user.valid?
assert(user.errors.has_key?(:username)) # pass
assert(user.errors.has_key?(:email)) # pass
```

When you print out the errors with `user.errors.full_messages()` it will contain both `Email has already been taken` and `Username has already been taken`.

But if you override the message like so:

```
validates :username, :email, uniqueness: { message: 'Username&email must be unique' }
```

You will get `Username&email must be unique` twice instead, which is not so great.

If for some reason you really need to have only one error you would add a custom validation method:

```
validate :uniqueness_of_username_and_email

def uniqueness_of_username_and_email
  if User.where("username = ? OR email = ?", username, email).any?
    errors.add(:email_username, 'Username&email must be unique')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I've noticed that it will generate separate validate for each field, but it doesn't work anyway. The problem is not the way it works, but that it does work (!) if ran as an application and I'm checking it on my views, but it won't work if I check the same things with tests

Comment: Could it be that the duplicate value is `null`? A typical postgres uniqueness index will not allow two `null` values but `validates uniqueness` does allow a nil value.

Comment: It might be easier to troubleshoot if you actually wrote out the value of `user_params` in your test as its a pretty key piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Also add the `user_params` method from your controller - if you have forgotten to whitelist the username param it will be nil which would cause the `PG::UniqueViolation` since it is not "caught" by the models validations.

Comment: Added my users_params method, hope it helps to understand what is the problem

Comment: Can you add the UsersController#users_params method as well?